# How to compute all trigrams of a table in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

i have a table similar this

```
one
two
three
four
five 
six
seven
```

i need a function for this table with similar output

```
one-two-tree
two-three-four
three-four-five
...
```

[Wikipedia page on n-gram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-gram)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tested in MySQL.  First creating the data:

```
create table words(id integer auto_increment primary key, text varchar(255));
insert into words (text) values ('one');
insert into words (text) values ('two');
insert into words (text) values ('three');
insert into words (text) values ('four');
insert into words (text) values ('five');
insert into words (text) values ('six');
insert into words (text) values ('seven');
```

The query:

```
select
    t1.text as tx1,
    t2.text as tx2,
    t3.text as tx3
from
    words as t1,
    words as t2,
    words as t3
where
    (t1.id + 1) = t2.id
    and
    (t2.id + 1) = t3.id
;
```

It relies on word IDs being in sequence.  A string concatenation function can be used to combine 3 columns into one.

```
select
    concat(t1.text, '-',
           t2.text, '-',
           t3.text)
    as trigram
from
    words as t1,
    words as t2,
    words as t3
where
    (t1.id + 1) = t2.id
    and
    (t2.id + 1) = t3.id
;
```